# .scroll animation with javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to scroll page to a particular part of the page whenever the user clicks on corresponding menu link.For me document.getElementById("container").scrollTop is not working,So I am using document.body.scrollTop.It is always showing zero as the value.But it is not working.Could anybody help me?Here is my code...

```js
window.addEventListener("load",init,true);
function init()
{
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  for(var i = 0;i < nodes.length;i++)
  {
    nodes[i].addEventListener("click",function(){scrollAnimation(this.id)},true);
}
}
function scrollAnimation(id)
{
  var targetElementTop = document.getElementById(id+"_scroll").offsetTop;
scrollAnimate(targetElementTop);
}
function scrollAnimate(targetTop)
{
  var bodyScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
  if(bodyScrollTop < targetTop)
  {
  document.body.scrollTop += 5;
    setTimeout(function(){scrollAnimate(targetTop)},4);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="home">home</li>
    <li id="about_us">about us</li>
    <li id="careers">careers</li>
    <li id="our_team">our team</li>
    <li id="contact_us">contact us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="home_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is home page</div>
  <div>content </div>
</div>
<div id="about_us_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is about us page</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
<div id="careers_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is careers page</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
<div id="our_team_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is our team page</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
<div id="contact_us_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is contact us page</div>
  <div>content </div>
</div>
```

Where as document.body.scrollTop is working fine another code.

Comment: Try `window.scrollBy(0,5)` Instead of `document.body.scrollTop += 5;`

Comment: What browser are you testing this on? Some require you to use `document.documentElement` to read and adjust the `scrollTop` value of the whole document, so something like this will get you the correct value: `(document.documentElement ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop || 0`

Comment: I am using chrome @somethinghere

Comment: I want to scroll only if(bodyScrollTop < targetTop) @ZohirSalakCeNa

Answer (score 0):

On chrome, the `document.body.scrollTop` is not actually adjusted, you need `document.documentElement.scrollTop` for that. I added the `getScrollTop` and `setScrollTop` functions I use to set them correctly every time:

```js
function setScrollTop( value ){
  
  // Check if there is a documentElement, otherwise apply to document bodu
  // Apply to document body to be sure all possible places with scrollTop are updated.
  
  (document.documentElement ? document.documentElement : document.body).scrollTop = value;
  document.body.scrollTop = value;

}
function getScrollTop( value ){
    
  // First, see if there a documentElement with a scrollTop value bigger than 0
  // then, see if there is a body with a scrollTop value bigger than 0
  // If neither is bigger than 0, just return 0 for safety.
  
  return (document.documentElement ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop || 0;

}
function scrollAnimation(id){

  var top = document.getElementById(id+"_scroll").offsetTop;
  scrollAnimate( top );

}
function scrollAnimate(targetTop){

  var top = getScrollTop();

  if(top < targetTop){

    setScrollTop( top + 5 );
    setTimeout(function(){scrollAnimate(targetTop)},4);

  }

}

var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for( let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ){

  nodes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

    scrollAnimation( this.id );

  },true);

}
```

```css
div[id]{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="home">home</li>
    <li id="about_us">about us</li>
    <li id="careers">careers</li>
    <li id="our_team">our team</li>
    <li id="contact_us">contact us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="home_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is home page</div>
  <div>content </div>
</div>
<div id="about_us_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is about us page</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
<div id="careers_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is careers page</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
<div id="our_team_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is our team page</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
<div id="contact_us_scroll">
  <div class="heading">this is contact us page</div>
  <div>content </div>
</div>
```